# Из-за Rigidbody2D.MovePosition() персонаж ОЧЕНЬ долго падает

Tags: c#, unity3d

При использовании Rigidbody2D.MovePosition() персонаж передвигается нормально, но он очень долго падает, как будто у персонажа есть крылья и он их раскрыл. Убирал Rigidbody2D.MovePosition() и проблема пропадала, персонаж падал как обычно.
Вот код:

```
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Move();
    }
    
    public void Move()
    {
        _rigidbody.MovePosition(_rigidbody.position + Vector2.right * (_speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime));
    }
```

Пробовал заменять `FixedUpdate` и `Time.fixedDeltaTime` на `Update` и `Time.deltaTime`

Comment: можно как вариант попробовать поменять в св-вах rd mass и gravity scale на чуть большие значения.

Comment: @vadosinferno Нет не можно, проблема не в этом.  В 99 процентах случаев, когда хочется изменить массу или gravity scale, нужно просто  подумать и найти нормальный способ решить проблему.

Comment: Ок, в следующий раз буду думать прежде чем предлагать какие-либо варианты решения возникшей проблемы)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используя `MovePosition`, вы телепортируете объект, а не перемещаете его, поэтому скорость, которая была у объекта до перемещения обнуляется. Далее к объекту применяется физика, притягивает объект немного вниз. И так в каждом `FixedUpdate` поэтому объект не разгоняется.

Вместо `MovePosition` изменяйте скорость объекта напрямую через `_rigidbody.velocity`

Должно получиться что-то типа этого:

```
private void Move(float direction)
{
    var velocity = _rigidbody.velocity;
    velocity.x = _speed * direction;
    _rigidbody.velocity = velocity;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, помогло! Про то, что MovePosition-телепортация узнал впервые, буду знать)